# how to remove a directory or files in git bash to unstage them

Tags: git, git-status

I am checking status of me repo using " git status ". but it shows that i used to changes to be committed ,
here the commands are :

```
~/udacity-git-course/new-git-project (master)
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   webpage.html

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        course-git-blog-project/
        npm-debug.log
```

then i used the command

```
$ git rm --cached <webpage.html>...
```

but it shows

```
fatal: No pathspec was given.
```

Which files should I remove? I don't know how to correct it and resolve it.

Comment: The status of the repo seems to be that nothing has been committed?

Comment: `<file>` in the instructions is to be replaced by the actual filename. You are not supposed to keep the "less than" and "greater than" signs around it. On the same level, `...` means there could be other filenames to follow on the command line, you are not supposed to type this literally either => `git rm --cached webpage.html`

Answer (score 2):

First, let me put in this note: there's nothing wrong with having "changes to be committed".  This is just about the actions you took afterward.

---

This line:

```
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
```

is using angle brackets `<` and `>` to indicate that the word `file` is a placeholder.  The angle brackets themselves *must also be deleted* when you enter the command.  Furthermore, the three dots are meta-text meaning "repeat as needed".  So, instead of:

> ```
> git rm --cached <webpage.html>...
> ```

you were supposed to run:

```
git rm --cached webpage.html
```

(note lack of angle brackets and lack of three dots).

What happened here is that your *shell* "ate" the words `webpage.html` and `...` and did *I/O redirection*.  That is, you ran:<sup>1</sup>

```
<webpage.html >... git rm --cached
```

so that `git rm`'s *standard input* came from file `webpage.html` and its *standard output* went to (new) file `...`.  This will have left you with an extra file named `...` that will now be reported as an *untracked file;* you will need to remove that with:

```
rm ...
```

(note no angle brackets and no `git` prefix and so on).

You should work through a tutorial on the use of your shell (which appears to be bash, sh, or similar).

---

<sup>1</sup>I/O redirections can be placed anywhere along the command, though it's typical for humans to put them at the right edge.  That is, we tend to see:

```
generate-output --long >outfile
```

rather than:

```
>outfile generate-output --long
```

or the even weirder-looking:

```
generate-output >outfile --long
```

but all three perform the same action.